# how to iterate through each element in a matrix in r

Tags: r, loops, matrix

Context: I am iterating through several variables in my dataset, and performing a pairwise t.test between the factors for each of those variables. ( which i have succesfully managed to perform). and example of the result i have is as so:

[Table of P-values between classes 11,12,13 and 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjS1w.png)

My next task with which i am having difficulty with is presenting each of those values as a table where for each element, if its value is below a certain threshold (say .05) then the table should dynamically display if the test between the two classes passes ( represented by a 1 if below 0.05 and a 0 if above 0.05) the table should also display a ratio of the number of tests passed as a proportion of the number of tests conducted. ( number of entries in the table below 0.05 over the total number of entries in the **diagonal matrix**). In reference to the image above the output should look like this:
[Ideal Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mwAW.png)

And so the problem, is essentially that i have to iterate through the first matrix (exclude the first row and first column), apply a function then generate a new row and header with a row and column summary! Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please edit the question with the output of `dput(Table of P-values)`? (Your input matrix.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R` is not really a useful tool to build such a table, but here is one solution.

Data (shortened the decimals for convenience):

```
mat <- matrix(c(.569, .0001, .1211, NA, .0001, .3262, NA, NA, .0001), nrow = 3)

       [,1]   [,2]  [,3]
[1,] 0.5690     NA    NA
[2,] 0.0001 0.0001    NA
[3,] 0.1211 0.3262 1e-04
```

First we convert to the `0,1` scheme by using `ifelse` with the condition `< .05`:

```
mat <- ifelse(mat < .05, 1, 0)
```

Then we add another column with the `rowSums`:

```
mat <- cbind(mat, rowSums(mat, na.rm = T))
```

Then we add another row with the `colSums` of the boolean matrix `!is.na(mat)`, therefore counting the numbers of non `NA` per column:

```
mat <- rbind(mat, colSums(!is.na(mat)))
```

Then we change the lower right cell to the `sum` of the inner matrix divided by the amount of non `NA` of the inner matrix:

```
mat[nrow(mat), ncol(mat)] <- sum(mat[1:nrow(mat)-1, 1:ncol(mat)-1], na.rm = T)/
                             sum(!is.na(mat[1:nrow(mat)-1, 1:ncol(mat)-1]))
```

Finally, we change the row and column names:

```
rownames(mat) <- c(12:14, "SumCount")
colnames(mat) <- c(11:13, "SumScore")
```

End result:

```
> mat
         11 12 13 SumScore
12        0 NA NA      0.0
13        1  1 NA      2.0
14        0  0  1      1.0
SumCount  3  2  1      0.5
```

Notice that no looping was necessary, as `R` is very efficient with vectorized operations on matrices.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your detailed answer! My only issue is that  our last 2 steps eg. specifying the lower right cell are rather hard coded to a 3x3 matrix. How can i specify the bottom right cell of the matrix "without knowing the dimensions of the matrix". Similar issue for performing the sum operations!

Comment: Use `mat[nrow(mat), ncol(mat)]` instead. Additionally, to restrict to the inner matrix for the calculation in that row, you can use `mat[1:nrow(mat)-1, 1:ncol(mat)-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing what you want.

First I will make up a matrix.

```
set.seed(3781)
pval <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 0.07), 3)
is.na(pval) <- upper.tri(pval)
dimnames(pval) <- list(12:14, 11:13)
```

Now the question.

```
Ideal <- matrix(as.integer(pval < 0.05), nrow(pval))
dimnames(Ideal) <- dimnames(pval)
Ideal
#   11 12 13
#12  1 NA NA
#13  1  1 NA
#14  1  0  0


r <- sum(Ideal, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(!is.na(Ideal))
r
#[1] 0.6666667
```

So now all what is needed is to add the extra row and column.

```
Ideal <- rbind(Ideal, colSums(!is.na(Ideal)))
Ideal <- cbind(Ideal, rowSums(Ideal, na.rm = TRUE))
Ideal[nrow(pval) + 1, ncol(pval) + 1] <- r
rownames(Ideal)[nrow(pval) + 1] <- "SumCount"
colnames(Ideal)[nrow(pval) + 1] <- "SumScore"
```

Comment: Hi, Similar to the answer above, for last 3 steps. How can i specify the bottom right cell without indicating the column and row numbers! ( and the last row/column)

Comment: @BharatDesai If `pval` is your original matrix, instead of `4` use `nrow(pval) + 1` which is general purpose. I will edit the answer.